# Test of independence of a discrete variable and a categorial variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence

I have data from an experiment with three groups A, B and C (categorical variable) and I want to show that the groups are homogenous regarding the distribution of the age (discrete variable) of the participants in the three groups.

Which test do you recommend to use? Would it be ok to report that I found no significant Pearson-Correlation between the groups (0,1,2) and age?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "show" that, I'd advise you to use a box plot of age by category.

Another usual way is to just show the mean and standard deviation for each group. If you really want to test the homogeneity, you could use the appropriate tests to see if the means and standard deviations of the groups are different. Which test to use depends on the age distribution, usually it's pretty normal and you're safe using an ANOVA for the means, and an F test the variances.

What you do depends a bit on how thorough you want to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As the means are different between the groups I want to use a test. However, I wonder why you recommend me an ANOVA. Isn't that true, that if an ANOVA is not significant I can not necessarily conclude that the groups are homogeneous? I thought about testing the correlation as in the case that I have two categorial variables, I normally apply a chi square test to test whether the two categorical variables are homogeneous. http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/homogeneity.aspx?Tutorial=AP
Thanks

Comment: The point is that most people wouldn't consider age a categorical variable. Technically speaking it is, but given the number of categories plus the fact that it has an absolute zero and is ordered it is mostly considered a ratio scale. That's why suggested you started with comparing means AND standard deviations/variance. If you want to be really sure you could probably use something like the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)